# JavaFX LineChart using SceneBuilder

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder, linechart

I'm trying to make a simple LineChart with some random info, but when I try to do it with a fxml file though SceneBuilder the Chart shows but never gets filled. Whenever I create the vbox,linechart and scene manually everything works fine. I'm really confused where the chart code should go when using the fxml file.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    LineChart chart1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //Through FXML
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Chart Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

        //Manually
//        LineChart chart1;
//        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
//        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
//        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
//        xAxis.setLabel("X Axis");
//        yAxis.setLabel("Y Axis");
//        series1.setName("Series 1");
//        chart1 = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
//        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1, 20));
//        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2, 100));
//        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(3, 80));
//        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(4, 180));
//        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(5, 20));
//        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(6, -10));
//        chart1.getData().add(series1);
//        VBox vbox=new VBox(chart1);
//        Scene scene=new Scene(vbox,600,400);
//        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
//        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    LineChart chart1;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("X Axis");
        yAxis.setLabel("Y Axis");
        series1.setName("Series 1");
        chart1 = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1, 20));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2, 100));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(3, 80));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(4, 180));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(5, 20));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(6, -10));
        chart1.getData().add(series1);
    }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="356.0">
         <center>
            <LineChart fx:id="chart1" title="Chart Test" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
              <xAxis>
                <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
              </xAxis>
              <yAxis>
                <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
              </yAxis>
            </LineChart>
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Don't create a new line chart; it is (presumably) already created in the FXML file.

Comment: Okay, so how do I pass xAxis and yAxis to it?

Comment: Well presumably you are doing that in the FXML file too... Can you post the FXML file in the question?

Comment: Added the fxml to the code

Comment: OK, so your FXML defines the chart and both axes. There is no need to create new ones in the controller. (The chart you create in the controller is never added to the scene graph, which is why you don't see the data it displays.) Get rid of the axes in the `initialize()` method, and the line `chart1 = new LineChart(...)`.

Comment: Like this?

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("Series 1");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1, 20)); ...

Still not working. I get an error on primaryStage.show

Comment: Yeah, but you also need to fix the types of the data (in one chart you have `String` for the x-values, and in the other you have `Number`). See answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already created a `LineChart` and the axes in your FXML file with the code

```xml
<LineChart fx:id="chart1" title="Chart Test" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
  <xAxis>
    <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
  </xAxis>
  <yAxis>
    <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
  </yAxis>
</LineChart>
```

This chart is added to a border pane, which in turn is added to the grid pane that is returned from the `FXMLLoader.load()` method and placed in the scene.

However, in your `initialize()` method you then create *another* line chart:

```
chart1 = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
```

which you then proceed to populate with data. Since this new line chart is never displayed in the scene, you never see the data.

Also, note there is a discrepancy between the two charts: in the one created in the FXML you have a `CategoryAxis`, which is an `Axis<String>` as the x-axis, but in the chart created in the controller you use a `NumberAxis` as the x-axis. You probably want a `NumberAxis`, so change the FXML:

```xml
<LineChart fx:id="chart1" title="Chart Test" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
  <xAxis>
    <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
  </xAxis>
  <yAxis>
    <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
  </yAxis>
</LineChart>
```

and then simply remove the creation of the second line chart (and the second set of axes):

```
@FXML
LineChart<Number, Number> chart1;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series1.setName("Series 1");
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1, 20));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2, 100));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(3, 80));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(4, 180));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(5, 20));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(6, -10));
    chart1.getData().add(series1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Had to modify the fxml file manually because I don't know how to change the axis from categoryAxis to numberAxis in SceneBuilder

Comment: @Arigatex Doesn't seem to be a way to change that in Scene Builder: this is currently [filed as a bug](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/107/gluons-scenebuilder-issue)